# Matching the lines that have more then one space and printing them

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a 23 folders and each folder has two subfolders (always same name) and each subfolder has exactly two files (always same name). So it looks like this:

```
Folder1/BindingDB/chiral.smi
                 nochiral.smi
Folder1/Xray/chiral.smi
             nochiral.smi

 Folder2/BindingDB/chiral.smi
                     nochiral.smi
 Folder2/Xray/chiral.smi
                 nochiral.smi
```

For example `chiral.smi` file looks like this:

```
COCCNC(=O)[C@H]1[C@@H]([C@H]2CN3C(=O)C=CC=C3[C@@H]1N2C4=NC(=C(S4)C5=CC=CC=C5)C6=CC=C(C=C6)Cl)CO K00000004
C1[C@H]2[C@H](C=C([C@H]3[C@@H]2[C@H]4[C@@H]1[C@@H]([C@H]4C=C3)CC/C=C/CC5=CC=C(C=C5)O)C(=O)O)O  K00000005
C[C@]12CCC[C@@]([C@@H]1CC[C@@]34[C@H]2C[C@H]5[C@@H](C3)[C@]5(C4)CO)(C)C(=O)O  K00000006
```

So here, last two lines `K00000005` and `K00000006` have double space and I want to match these two lines.

I am trying to double check all `chiral.smi` and `nochiral.smi` files in my folders if they have lines that have double space (I should only have one space in each line of each file).

I have tried in bash something like this:

`for i in */*/*.smi ; do sed -e "s/\s\{2,\}/  /g" $i; done` but it is not working. Also, when I run `sed -e "s/\s\{3,\}/  /g" *smi` in subfolder (BindingDB or Xray) it prints all the lines that have only one space. Can anyone help me since I cannot figure out whats the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to *check* the files - or correct them?

Comment: I am trying to check the files..but I came across the idea to open all of them in one txt file and then I just searched for double space and havent found it so it should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can list the *names* of any `.smi` files in which any line contains two adjacent spaces with

```
grep --include='*.smi' -rl '  ' .
```

If you want to output the lines themselves, then remove the `l` option.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, something like

```
grep -l '  ' */*/*.smi
```

will print the "double space" filenames

If you want do normalize spaces (`'  '` -> `' '`) you can try to

```
sed -ri.bak 's/\s{2,}/ /g' */*/*.smi
```

and remove the backup files if all went well

```
rm /*/*.smi.bak
```